# Simple way of disabling HTML inside input fields and textareas without server side languages?

Tags: javascript, html

So I just found this out that when you use JavaScript to show the contents of input fields and textareas, they can show HTML code as well. 
Is there a way to disable HTML inside those fields and only allow specific tags?

This is  the method I am using to load the cotents of those fields.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('QueryTitle');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('QueryTitleOutput').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
 
  var textarea = document.getElementById('QueryInput');

textarea.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('QueryOutputFrame').innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--This is the title field -->
   <input type="text" id="QueryTitle" placeholder="Ask Something">
   <br>
    <br>
   <!--This is the contents of the query -->
    <textarea id="QueryInput" style="width: 780px; height: 200px;">
     </textarea>
    <!--This is the area that loads the elements of the title field -->
     <div id="QueryTitleOutput">
     </div>
       <br> 
      <br>   
     <!--This is the area that loads the conents of the question -->
   <div id="QueryOutputFrame" style="width: 90%; height: 10em;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse values in keyup functions.

```
const goodTags = ['<span>','</span>']
var tag = inputBox.value.match(/<.+>/)
if (tag && !goodTags.includes?(tag[0])) { inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(tag[0], '') }
```